# Data structure : "likeable" object

Tags: mysql, data-structures, architecture

I'm currently working on a app that has a lot of different Model which are "likeable". This means each of them can be liked/disliked.

Is it better to create an unique table "likes", and referencing in each row the table reference + the table reference id, or to create an unique "likes" associated table for each likeable Model ?

Comment: What are your use cases? How are these 'models' used?

Comment: For various uses, example I can have a Post model, an Comment model, an Photo model, each likeable. I don't know If I asnwered your question.

Comment: Well, not completely, it's important to know what you want to do with those 'models'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. It depends on many things. What you've described is only a small portion of the problem space I'm assuming. There are important questions to be asked here, like, "Do you need to keep track of what user 'liked' what model?" Answers to questions like that will heavily influence the design of this database.

Having a separate 'like' table hanging off of each model table is what we call de-normalized. It's not necessarily a bad thing, it just depends on what your plan is for this data store. The normalized approach would be to have a single 'like' table that all the model tables relate to.

For this, you really need more information. Once you have ALL of the requirements in place, it should become a lot more clear TO YOU, what the best approach is.